# Include <string> in xcode 5?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I'm trying to port some Android JNI code to iOS and I'm getting the error

'string' file not found when I try to compile the code in XCode 5.1.1

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Source is inlined, the __cplusplus ifndef is something I just added after reading some other answers (it didn't help).

```
/*
 * saveload.h
 * --------------------------
 * Declares functions relating to saving and loading from files.
 * This file is around for backwards compatibility, as we now use
 * proto saving and loading instead.
 */

#ifndef SAVELOAD_H_INCLUDED
#define SAVELOAD_H_INCLUDED

#ifndef __cplusplus
#include <string>
#endif
```

Comment: make sure it is not included by .m/.c files.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <string>
#endif
```

See the makefile log. It must be have C++ headers in its include path.

Comment: the `Xcode` is throwing an error `'string' file not found` as said in the description. so i don't really know how the include line is working?

Comment: Search the string header file in Xcode.app folder. And make sure where it is, its include path must be in your configuration.

Comment: dbasic I can't understand what you said. The question tells that Xcode is not able to find the file but the answer you suggested is to change the pre-processors and if that was the error then how the file got included in the first place.

Comment: @bikram990: Also read C++ headers in include path. It means that it is not able to find string header file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that my C++ files were .cc and not .mm files.